# FlatUI - radio buttons jQuery compatibility

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

My current project's configuration is:

- Ruby on Rails 4.0.1, with turbo links
- jQuery 1.10.2 (from google's CDN)
- FlatUI Pro version 1.2.2, which includes
- "flatui-radio.js" v0.0.3

I am trying to integrate it's radio buttons using the html provided:

```
<label class="radio">
  <input type="radio" name="group1" value="2" data-toggle="radio" checked>
  Radio is on
</label>
```

I am facing the same issue as described in their support, "https://github.com/designmodo/Flat-UI-Pro-Support/issues/52": Radio buttons work only when I downgrade to jQuery 1.8.3.

Is there any reason on why this is happening?
Does anyone have a patch/workaround for later versions of jQuery? I have coded the whole application against it and I am afraid that it might break the application somewhere else.

Comment: I tried to create FlatUI tag, but no reputation

Comment: Thanks for letting me know about this - had the same problem, and reverting to 1.8.3 worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if this question is quite old, I recently faced this problem, so here is the fix I used to make the radio buttons work in Firefox:

At line 54 of [flatui-radio.js](https://github.com/designmodo/Flat-UI/blob/master/js/flatui-radio.js):

```
$el.get(0).checked = true;
```

Wrap this code in a if statement if you want or simply add it at the end of the statement:

```
if (checked == false) $parent.addClass(ch) && $el.prop(ch, true) && $el.get(0).checked = true;
```

Without this fix, the DOM element corresponding with the radio button never has the "checked" property set to true, even if the "checked" attribute was set. 
You may also use the same trick with checkboxes.

Comment: I am no longer maintaining that code base. Another consideration is that FlatUI updates it's code base and allows download of new updates, so it might have been fixed in a subsequent version. If anyone got helped please update so that I can accept the answer...

Comment: I am currently working on a Flat UI based website with jQuery and Flat UI both up-to-date. My answer has been tested on this website.

Comment: Since I cannot replicate and you're so confident accepting it.